# arm inline assembly in NDK, how to deal with pointers and pointed data?

Tags: gcc, android-ndk, arm, inline-assembly

I am trying to do an operation with assembly over an address pointed by a c pointer, now the problem i have is that i can't find the way to pass the pointer to a register and then do my operation in the data then store the value to another output pointer.

here is my code:
what am i missing?

```
void asmfunc(short *pOut, short *pIn) {
    asm volatile(
            "ldr r0, [in];"
            "ldr r1, [out];"
            "mov r2, r0;"
            "lsr r2, [r2], #1;"
            "str r1, [r2];"
            :[out] "=m" (pOut)
            :[in] "m" (pIn)
    );
}
```

Comment: [in] -> %[in], [out] -> %[out], lsr won't access memory for you. There should be plenty of tutorials about these. http://www.ethernut.de/en/documents/arm-inline-asm.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're actually doing there is *loading* the value from the output pointer, then using the result of the shift as an address to store it to. Note that you also need to tell the compiler that you're using more registers than the ones it knows about and changing values in memory, or eventually subtle bugs will bite you. The equivalent to what I *think* you're trying to do would be something like this -

```
void asmfunc(short *pOut, short *pIn) {
    asm volatile(
            "ldr r3, %[in]\n"
            "lsr r3, r3, #1\n"
            "str r3, %[out]\n"
            :[out] "=m" (*pOut)
            :[in] "m" (*pIn)
            :"r3", "memory"
    );
}
```

Comment: +1, nitpick: a good example should also not use r0 as clobber since it is pOut to start with.

Comment: @auselen Very true, thanks for the reminder - I've made it more EABI-friendly.

Comment: i can't make it work it trows the following error
jni/opensl_mic.c:129:5: error: unknown register name 'r3' in 'asm'
make.exe: *** [obj/local/x86/objs/opensl_mic/opensl_mic.o] Error 1
do you know why it might be?

Comment: my mistake i had the x86 directive in my Application.mk it works perfectly fine

Comment: It seems that  you need `(*pOut)` and `(*pIn)` at least with gcc 4.8.2; otherwise, it saves r0,r1 on the stack and operates on those copies.